# @ instagram api : Getting the results based on complex boolean expression

Tags: instagram

@ instagram api : As we can write description of a photo (160 characters ) in Instagaram. I want to utilize this information.

Q: Can I create a complex search expression like `FIFAorFOOTBALLandFRANCEnotSPAIN` which gives me the images having fifa, football and france in description field but not the spain.

Answer (score 0):

The Instagram API only supports searching a single tag at a time.

Comment: @ Bill..I got your point..It searches by single tag only...But since we can write description of a photo in 160 character. Then the search can be done using words present in the description or not?